# Автоматический меняет код ckeditor?

Tags: html, css, ckeditor

Всем привет. Пользуюсь редактором ckeditor. Когда вставляю следующий html код

```
<div class="window-link">
                    <a class="order_master" style="cursor: pointer;">
                        <img src="img/w1.png" alt="">
                    <div class="w-name">
                        Вызвать<br>замерщика
                    </div>
                    </a>
                </div>
```

Он его записывает в БД. Потом я открывают что бы его отредактировать но он загружает его в таком формате

```
<div class="window-link">
        <a class="order_master" style="cursor: pointer;"> 
            <img alt="" src="img/w1.png" /> 
        </a>
        <div class="w-name">
            <a class="order_master" style="cursor: pointer;">
                Вызвать<br />замерщика 
            </a>
        </div>
        <a class="order_master" style="cursor: pointer;"> </a>
    </div>
```

т.е. Добавляет кучу ссылок, хотя в оригинал только одна ссылка которая обворачивет почти весь блок. Что делать?

Comment: Вероятно, ckeditor [проверяет валидность](http://ckeditor.com/forums/Support/Disable-HTML-correction) такой разметки. Согласно спеке [HTML 4.01](https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/links.html#edef-A)  тегом "а" можно оборачивать только inline элементы. DIV - это блочный элемент. Что будет, если заменить DIV на SPAN?

Comment: Можно что нибудь сделать что бы он не придерживался этого правила? Прописал в config.js CKEDITOR.config.allowedContent = true;  не помогло

Comment: Не знаю насчет актуальности на данный момент, но вот этот [тикет](http://dev.ckeditor.com/ticket/7961) содержит некоторые рекомендации по workaround'у, в частности, начиная с 10го комментария